# Temporary field on Grails Service class if used within certain context

Tags: spring, grails

So, I'm using a Grails service class within a Quartz job. Now, whenever the service is used within the context of the job I want to set the job as a field on the service, because the service does some special logic if executing within the context of the job, and it needs access to the job object to do so. Would the easiest/safest thing to do be to just create a new instance of my service class and set the job on it and use that, rather than the injected version of the service? I'm worried that if I use the injected copy of the service and set the job on it and some totally bizarre error happens where my clean up logic doesn't run, the service would have that job set on it even after the job executed.

Hopefully that makes some sense. Here's a super dumbed down example of what I'm doing.

```
class TestService {
    def job

    def someMethod() {
       //Some logic
       if (job != null) {
           //Job specific logic
       }
    }
}

class TestJob {
    def execute(context) {
       def service = new TestService()
       service.job = this

       service.sometMethod()
    }
}
```

Very dumbed down, but does that seem like the safest way to make sure the job doesn't remain set on the spring defined version of the service.

Comment: This is a question - even if the job field is still set to point to the job instance, will the job be null once the Quartz job has finished running? This assumes Quartz destroys the job instance, otherwise the reference from your service will stop it being garbage collected, probably. I suppose you could test this?

Comment: Services are singletons (you can probably configure Spring to change this) so doing a "new" won't work to set other values on your service unless they store state in a DB, etc. What is the Quartz job actually doing?